# Permission issues on schema.gql

Tags: docker, graphql, nestjs

I'm using docker to run  NestJS & GraphQL. I built all images successfully and was able to start the services but for some reason, I can't send requests with Altair Graphql client because I can't have access to schemal.gql

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine

ARG user
ARG uid

# Clear cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Create a user and group with the provided arguments
RUN addgroup -g $uid $user \
    && adduser -u $uid -D -G $user $user

WORKDIR /statrics-server

# Create the user's home directory and set ownership
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user \
    && chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

COPY package.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-scripts

COPY . .

RUN chmod 777 ./* -Rf

USER $user

CMD ["yarn", "dev-server"]
```

**compose.yml file**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
     
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    ports: 
      - '5432:5432'
    env_file: 
    - ./server/.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  
  pgamdin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    ports:
      - '50:80'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgres
   
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/dev/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - '60:80'

  api: 
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    build: 
      args:
        user: app-user
        uid: 2000
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev      
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports: 
      - '4000:4000'
    volumes:
      - ./server:/statrics-server
    depends_on:
      - Postgres
```

**server folder structure (/server/)**

[image]

**The error I'm getting**

The error is shown by the red down arrow.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  This image happens to be fairly readable to most humans, but it'd be better practice to [edit] the question and include the error message in plain text instead of an image.)

Answer (score 0):

The `volumes:` block in the Compose file is hiding almost everything the Dockerfile does in its filesystem, including the `chown` and `chmod` statements.  The `USER` statement still takes effect, though.  If you're in a situation where the directories on the host are not world-readable and are not owned by the specified user ID, you could get a "permission denied" error.

I'd fix this entirely by deletion.  Consider a setup where:

- You do not overwrite the image's code with a bind mount;
- All source files are owned by root, but world-readable;
- Your container runs as an arbitrary non-root user.

You won't be able to overwrite your application's sources, intentionally or otherwise, but this isn't usually a problem.  Changes on the host filesystem won't be immediately reflected in the container without rebuilding the image, but you can still point a host Node environment at your other containers and this avoids several reported problems where the bind mount doesn't work.

This means you should:

- Delete the `volumes:` block in the Compose file for the `api` service
- Delete the `ARG` statements in the Dockerfile, and the matching Compose `build: { args: }`.
- When you `RUN adduser`, pick a fixed username and don't specify a uid.
- Especially don't `RUN chmod 777 ...` files.

This would reduce the Dockerfile to

```bash
FROM node:14-alpine

# Create a user and group with the provided arguments
RUN adduser user

WORKDIR /statrics-server

COPY package.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-scripts

COPY . .

USER user

CMD ["yarn", "dev-server"]
```